# Cordova (v 5.4.0) + FileWriter + FileOpener2 + Base64 String

Tags: angularjs, cordova, pdf, base64

I'm using AngularJS + Cordova to build an app

In one of my controllers, I do an API call, which returns a base64 String.

I need to take that Base64 string, decode it to a PDF, and display it in external app (Example Adobe PDF Viewer).

Here's what I have. I get success all round, but as soon as I try and open the file, I get nothing. I can't even find the file on the filesystem. Its as if nothing actually gets created, but why all the success messages then?

```
var pdfDetails = 'a very nice long base 64 string comes here';

                    contentType = 'application/pdf';

                    var fs;

                    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, pdfDetails.length, function (fileSystem) {
                        fs = fileSystem;

                        fileSystem.root.getFile("attachment.pdf", { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {
                            fileEntry.createWriter(function (writer) {
                                writer.fileName = "attachment.pdf";
                                writer.onwrite = function (evt) {
                                    // success!
                                    // BUT WHERE DOES THE FILE SIT? I can't find it anywhere...

                                    cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
                                            fs.root.toURL() + "attachment.pdf", 
                                            'application/pdf', 
                                            { 
                                                error : function(e) { 
                                                    console.log('Error status: ' + e.status + ' - Error message: ' + e.message);
                                                },
                                                success : function () {
                                                    console.log('file opened successfully');                
                                                }
                                            }
                                        );

                                };
                                writer.onerror = function () {
                                    // handle error
                                    console.log("ERROR 4");
                                };

                                writer.write(pdfDetails);
                            }, function (error) {
                                // handle error
                                console.log("ERROR 3");
                            });
                        }, function (error) {
                            // handle error
                            console.log("ERROR 2");
                        });

                    }, function (error) {
                          // handle error
                        console.log("ERROR 1");
                    });
```

I even get "File Opened Successfully" at the end of it all. Adobe PDF Viewer opens, but then says that it can't find the file. I'm out of options. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get it working.

Basically, the application was writing the file to its own private folder. I just had to move it, and then the external app would have been open the file.

Here's the working code....

```
$scope.$on('get-view-attachment-success', function(event, data) {

            /** The actual base64 string **/
                $scope.attachment_src = data.data.rows.base64; 

            /** I returned the type of document, cause it could be PDF or Image */
                $scope.attachment_type = data.data.rows.type;

                if ($scope.attachment_type == 'pdf') {

                    var pdfDetails = $scope.attachment_src;

                    contentType = 'application/pdf';

                    var fileSystem;

                    function onFs(fs) {

                        fileSystem = fs;

                    /** I�m hardcoding the filename here **/
                        fs.root.getFile('application.pdf', {create: true, exclusive: false},
                                function(fileEntry) {

                                    // Create a FileWriter object for our FileEntry (log.txt).
                                        fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {

                                            fileWriter.onwriteend = function(e) {

                                            fileEntry.file(function(file) {

                                                var sourceFilePath = file.localURL;
                                                //var targetFilePath = fileSystem.root.toURL()+fileDestPath + file.name;


                                                var deviceType = (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))  == "iPad" ? "iPad" : (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i))  == "iPhone" ? "iPhone" : (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) == "Android" ? "Android" : (navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)) == "BlackBerry" ? "BlackBerry" : "null";

                                                if (deviceType != "iPhone" && deviceType != "iPad") {
                                                    var targetFilePath = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory + file.name;
                                                } else {
                                                    var targetFilePath = cordova.file.tempDirectory + file.name;
                                                }

                                                var ft = new FileTransfer();
                                                ft.download(
                                                        sourceFilePath,
                                                        targetFilePath,
                                                        function(entry){

                                                        /** Now we can finally open the file we just created **/
                                                            cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
                                                                targetFilePath,
                                                                contentType,
                                                                {
                                                                    error : function(e) {
                                                                        console.log('Error status: ' + e.status + ' - Error message: ' + e.message);
                                                                    },
                                                                    success : function () {
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            );
                                                        },
                                                        function(error){
                                                            console(error);
                                                        }
                                                );

                                            }, onError);

                                        };

                                        /** This part saved my life. Covert the Base64 string to a Blob **/
                                        function b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType) {
                                            contentType = contentType || '';
                                            var sliceSize = 512;
                                            b64Data = b64Data.replace(/^[^,]+,/, '');
                                            b64Data = b64Data.replace(/\s/g, '');
                                            var byteCharacters = window.atob(b64Data);
                                            var byteArrays = [];

                                            for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
                                                    var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

                                                    var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
                                                for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
                                                        byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
                                                    }

                                                    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

                                                    byteArrays.push(byteArray);
                                            }

                                            var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
                                            return blob;
                                        }

                                        var blob = b64toBlob(pdfDetails , contentType);

                                        fileWriter.write(blob);

                                    }, onError);

                                }, onError
                                );
                    }

                    if (window.isphone) {

                        window.requestFileSystem(TEMPORARY, 0, onFs, onError);

                    }

                    /** General Error Catcher **/
                    function onError(err) {
                        console.log("Oops! : " , err);
                    }

                }

                $scope.event_id = data.data.rows.event_id;
            });
```